# Ruby on rails: model name uninitialized error (mismatch of module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, mode, activeresource, uninitialized-constant

I am accessing model Company::Item in controller Security::MyController. It is giving error uninitialised constant Security::Company::Item . So basically it is appending 'Security::'  for given model. It is not the case with some other models say Security::User(model in same module security). What could be possible explanation for this?

Comment: please post the code in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope resolution problem. You should try using `::Company::Item`inside `Security::MyController`

According to Ruby Language Spec

```
::Something is a shortcut for Object::Something. The idea is that ::Something 
should look up a constant called Something in the global scope, but since ruby 
doesn't truly have a global scope, it looks it up in the Object class, which is 
the nearest thing in ruby to a global scope.
```

Prefixing :: will prevent Ruby from applying the default scope in that context, which in your case, is the `Security::` scope